# Summarise a set of dates contained in a column

Tags: r, summarize

I have a dataset with transactions made from 2018/07/01 to 2019/06/30 and I want to find how many unique dates are in the "DATE" column (it has over 260k rows, so a date can be repeated several times).

I have tried the following but it just lists all the dates contained in the "DATE" column:

```
numberofdates <- dplyr::summarize(transactionData, DATE)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `length(unique(transactionData$DATE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of these approaches:

In `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code 1
numberofdates <- transactionData %>% summarize(n_distinct(DATE))
```

Or in `base R`:

```
#Code 2
length(unique(transactionData$DATE))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table` we can use

```
 library(data.table)
 numberofdates <- uniqueN(transactionData$DATE)
```